# IndexRoute not working for "/"

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a router with react-router 2.4 that looks like:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute, Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import * as Pages from 'pages';
import App from 'containers/App/App';
import store from './stores';

function requireAuth(nextState, replace) {
  if (!store.getState().user) {
    replace('/login');
  }
}

export default function render() {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route path="login" component={Pages.Login} />
          <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={requireAuth}>
            <IndexRoute component={Pages.Dashboard} />
            <Route path=":list_id" component={Pages.List} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('lists')
  );
}
```

Everything works except the IndexRoute. If I put the IndexRoute inside the App context, it doesn't work. If I put it outside of the App context, then it works. How can I define a route for "/" that's within the App context while allowing for other routes like Login to be outside of it?

My App render the `this.props.children` properly, since it works as expected for the List component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same `path = '/'` multiple times, instead of that use unique path values also make login as a separate route.

Define the routes like this:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/login" component={Pages.Login} />
    <Route path="/" component={App} onEnter={requireAuth}>
        <IndexRoute component={Pages.Dashboard} />
        <Route path=":list_id" component={Pages.List} />
    </Route>       
</Router>
```

Comment: If I do it like that, then the App context is shown independently of if the user is Authed. I update question so that you can see the logic for this

Comment: also, I have to put /login above or "login" becomes :list_id

Comment: *App context is shown independently of if the user is Authed,* didn't get this.

Comment: I meant that what the "App" component loads, is shown independently of if the user is logged in. But nevermind, it's another issue unrelated to this one. Thanks for helping out!

Comment: i think for that you can put the check inside `App` component.